# On the Covering in terms of Dyadic Cubes

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis

The following is an excerpt from a paper by Kerman and Sawyer:

(The underlying space is $\mathbb{R}^{n}$).

Each cube $Q$ is covered by at most $2^{n}$ dyadic cubes $\{I_{j}\}_{1\leq j\leq 2^{n}}$ with $2^{-n}|Q|\leq|I_{j}|\leq|Q|$.

I am justifying this statement.

Let $i\in\mathbb{Z}$ be such that $2^{i}\leq\ell(Q)<2^{i+1}$. Denote by $S=\{I~{\rm dyadic}:\ell(I)=2^{i},I\cap Q\ne\emptyset\}$. The dyadic cubes $I$ in $S$ cover $Q$ and $|I|\leq|Q|$. Now we have
\begin{align*}
|Q|=\sum_{I\in S}|I\cap Q|.
\end{align*}
I am trying to argue that the number of elements of $S\leq 2^{n}$ but fail to do so.

Comment: Personally I think that the dimensional constant $2^{n}$ seems not correct. For the cube with vertices $(-0.5,0.5)$, $(2.5,0.5)$, $(-0.5,-2.5)$, and $(2.5,-2.5)$ on the plane, how can you cover this at most $4$ dyadic cubes with such condition?

Answer (score 1):

I hope the following is correct.

Fix an $I_{j}\in S$. Consider any $I_{k}\in S$ in the first quadrant. Denote by $I_{k}'$ the parental dyadic cube that containing $I_{k}$. Then
\begin{align*}
\sum_{\substack{I\in S\\ I~\text{in the first quadrant}}}|I\cap Q|\leq|I_{k}'|=2^{n}|I_{k}|=2^{n}|I_{j}|.
\end{align*}
There are $2^{n}$ quadrants, decompose the sum $\sum_{I\in S}|I\cap Q|$ into quadrants sums, then we have the bound for $4^{n}$.